# How to call an ArcGIS rest service using Fiddler?

Tags: rest, fiddler, arcgis

I am trying to call an ArcGIS service using Fiddler but I can't seem to get it to return data.

Request:

GET http://services1.arcgis.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/ArcGIS/rest/services/WorldTimeZonesNamed/FeatureServer/query?layerDefs=0&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&geometry={xmin:-109.55,ymin:25.76,xmax:-109.55,ymax:25.76,spatialReference:{wkid:4326}}&f=json HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: services1.arcgis.com
Content-Length: 0

Response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-ArcGIS-Instance: MTSDS_Web_IN_14
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2016 14:43:19 GMT
Content-Length: 98

{"error":{"code":400,"message":"","details":["Operation without query criteria is not allowed."]}}

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to specify which output fields should be returned (outFields=*). I was also able to use a point geometry type instead of an envelope so I could send a single coordinate pair instead of an envelope (rectangle):

GET http://services1.arcgis.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/ArcGIS/rest/services/WorldTimeZonesNamed/FeatureServer/0/query?geometry={'x':-55.748800,'y':48.758563}&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&f=json HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler Host: services1.arcgis.com Content-Length: 0

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you need to send the `where`Clause parameter along with the request. If there is no condition then you should send "1=1" as your criteria.